# jQuery for each loop is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach, each

I am using jQuery `for each` loop. But its strange that the inner loop is not getting executed. I am attaching the info on how the outer and inner loops are executed.

```
$.each(arrForGrade, function(j, itemJ) {
    //currentLoad++;
    $.each(arrForSubject, function(k, itemK) {
        //Something
    });
});
```

It doesn't enter the inner loop and directly breaks out of the loop. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

Comment: Where is `arrForGrade` assigned a value? What value? What are the values of `arrForSubject`? Have you verified them with `console.log()`?

Comment: `arrForGrade` is not defined. What is the question?

Comment: @PHPglue  
arrForGrade is the outer loop and when pressed net line the initial values are assigned. arrForSubject is an innerLoop. So i am thinking that there si some issue with the inner loop s it already set the initial parameters in for j and itemJ

Comment: `arrForGrade` might have its initial value assigned, but does `arrForGrade` hold its value before the loop? maybe some other code resets `arrForGrade ` to undefined.

Comment: @Neverever yes . It holds. I have added the third image on how is it looking just while entering the loop.

Comment: do you have `ajax` calls running that might modify the value of `arrForGrade `? or part of the inner loop code is modifying `arrForGrade` ?

Comment: For the first time itself without any ajax call its becoming undefined. Not sure why it becomes undefined suddenly without any assignements. @Neverever

Comment: @SMP, you might have to show the whole JavaScript code, I can guarantee you that the problem is not on `$.each`, it's somewhere else in the code that's causing the exception

Answer (score 1):

Your [images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8rn6.png) tell the whole story. arrForGrade is undefined, so trying to iterate over it will not work, as you cannot iterate over something that doesn't exist.

Comment: arrForGrade is the outer loop and when pressed net line the initial values are assigned. arrForSubject is an innerLoop. So i am thinking that there si some issue with the inner loop s it already set the initial parameters in for j and itemJ @EKW

Comment: There isn't a problem with the inner loop. The problem is that arrForGrade is undefined. When the first `$.each` is called, arrForGrade is undefined, thus throwing an error and preventing execution of the loop's contents

Comment: added the third image. arrForGrade holds the values initially. it just becomes undefined after entering the loop.

Comment: According to the code that I can see, it should work. The only explanation is that there is something inside the inner loop messing it up. Please show the code inside the inner loop.

Comment: @EKW the dark blue line is breaking on the inner loop, so it looks like `arrForGrade` does have value just before the outer loop

Answer (score 0):

It's there, directly in your IMAGE2... `arrForGrade` is not defined. It's not that you're not getting into your inner loop, it's that you're not even getting into your outer loop.

Answer (score 0):

arrForGrade does not exist. that's why it doesn't enter in the first loop.
use them separated to get in.

```
$.each(arrForGrade, function(j, itemJ) {
    //currentLoad++;
});
$.each(arrForSubject, function(k, itemK) {
   //Something
});
```

cheers!